# Access Query to sum by day and count by hour / minute

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, subquery

I'm trying to write a query using the data below.  My challenge is for each day, I need to count the number of times "105" appears in Col A and "100" appears in Col B.  I do not need to count each instance "105" appears but rather each minute "105" appears.  Likewise with Col B and "100"

```
Date           Time      A   B
1/20/2021   1:06:12 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   1:06:16 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   1:06:20 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   2:28:12 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   2:28:16 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   2:28:20 AM  105 100
1/20/2021   3:50:08 AM  105 10
1/20/2021   3:50:12 AM  105 10
1/20/2021   3:50:16 AM  105 10
1/20/2021   5:12:04 AM  105 10
1/20/2021   5:12:08 AM  105 10
1/20/2021   5:12:12 AM  105 10
```

Detail:

```
Time  A  B
1:06  1  1
2:28  1  1
3:50  1  0
5:12  1  0
```

Query Result:

```
Date      A    B
1/21/20   4    2
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `distinct` on each column separately.  Then aggregate:

```
select date, sum(a), sum(b)
from (select distinct date, hour(time) as hh, minute(time) as mm, 1 as a, 0 as b
      from t
      where a = 105
      union all
      select distinct date, hour(time) as hh, minute(time) as mm, 0 as a, 1 as b
      from t
      where b = 100
     ) t
group by date;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff......I'm going to try this today.  The data types were Date/Time, Date/Time, Number, and Number.  Thanks for your help....

Comment: @gordonlinoff..............This works but I only need it to count Col B when Col A = 105.  Thanks...........

Comment: @Shaves . . . Then add that to the `where` clause.  Your question says "Likewise with Col B and "100"" which implies that you want to filter on the value for `B`.

Comment: @gordonlinoff.....Thanks..........sorry for the confusion.........I'm trying to Count A = 105 first and then for all of those records, I need to count b = 100 (for each minute).  Each minute can have multiple matches....I'll give that a try